# Pandas datetime with Julian Day

Tags: python, pandas

I tried searching for this and was surprised I couldn't find anything.  We use the term 'Julian Day' to refer to the day of the year irrespective of month (i.e. February 1st would be julian day 32).  I don't know if this is a regional term and maybe why I can't find any answers.

Basically I have two files. One has a standard date format with year, month, day, hour.  The other has year, julian day, hour.  I am trying to align them using pandas DataFrame function and don't know what to do about the missing month data.  Is Pandas able to convert this natively?

I am using python 3.3 and the newest version of Pandas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read in the Julian date file, you simply need to provide a custom date parsing function. Here's an examples:

```
import datetime
from io import StringIO
import pandas

datafile = StringIO("""\
jday,value
2013-01,1
2013-02,2
2013-100,8
2013-200,9
""")

dateparser = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%j')
df = pandas.read_csv(datafile, parse_dates=True, date_parser=dateparser, index_col=[0])
```

Which gives a `df` of:

```
            value
jday             
2013-01-01      1
2013-01-02      2
2013-04-10      8
2013-07-19      9
```

I keep [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm) bookmarked and handy for  "unconventional" date parsing needs such as these. (I don't actually think julian days are weird -- we use them all the time in hydraulic modeling)

Answer (score 4):

Try `dayofyear`. Julian day is actually a completely different number FYI, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

```
In [1]: pd.date_range('20130201',periods=5).dayofyear
Out[1]: array([32, 33, 34, 35, 36], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I realize that this is actually not the answer to your question, but the inverse.