# Parsing dates on different columns and with julian day using Pandas

Tags: python, parsing, csv, datetime, pandas

I have a CSV that is organized as

```
   0     1    2     3      4      5      6      7      8     9     10  11
0  42  2012  106  1200 -0.325  0.576 -0.295  31.73  14.80  1096  99.3  55
1  42  2012  106  1200 -0.372  0.499 -0.236  31.74  14.80  1097  99.3  56
2  42  2012  106  1200 -0.372  0.456 -0.212  31.74  14.80  1096  99.3  57
3  42  2012  106  1200 -0.312  0.736 -0.095  31.70  14.81  1097  99.3  58
4  42  2012  106  1200 -0.352  0.707 -0.035  31.66  14.78  1094  99.3  59
5  42  2012  106  1200 -0.518  0.662 -0.152  31.66  14.79  1094  99.3  60
6  42  2012  106  1200 -0.516  0.531 -0.249  31.78  14.79  1094  99.3  61
```

With columns 1, 2 and 3 being the year, Julian day and `%hour%minute`, respectively. I am trying to parse these columns as a datetime index, but I can't seem to do it.

I've tried some things, the most promising one was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500441/pandas-datetime-with-julian-day), so I wrote (assuming `fname` is the path to the file)

```
dateparse= lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %j %H%M')
pd.read_csv(fname, header=None, parse_dates=[[1,2,3]], date_parser=dateparse)
```

but this gives me the error

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

which indicates that apparently pandas isn't concatenating columns 1,2 and 3 and then applying the parser function, as I expected. If I read the csv only with

```
pd.read_csv(fname, header=None, parse_dates=[[1,2,3]])
DATA=data.set_index('1_2_3')
```

then I get

```
               0      4      5      6      7      8     9     10  11
1_2_3                                                               
2012 106 1200  42 -0.325  0.576 -0.295  31.73  14.80  1096  99.3  55
2012 106 1200  42 -0.372  0.499 -0.236  31.74  14.80  1097  99.3  56
2012 106 1200  42 -0.372  0.456 -0.212  31.74  14.80  1096  99.3  57
2012 106 1200  42 -0.312  0.736 -0.095  31.70  14.81  1097  99.3  58
2012 106 1200  42 -0.352  0.707 -0.035  31.66  14.78  1094  99.3  59
2012 106 1200  42 -0.518  0.662 -0.152  31.66  14.79  1094  99.3  60
2012 106 1200  42 -0.516  0.531 -0.249  31.78  14.79  1094  99.3  61
```

but the index isn't treated as a date, it is a string:

```
DATA.index
Index([u'2012 106 1200', u'2012 106 1200', u'2012 106 1200', u'2012 106 1200', ...], dtype='object')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dateparser like that will be very inefficient. Unless you have ISO dates, usually best to parse after.

But here it is. The key is that the `date_parser` takes the same number of arguments that you are passing (in this case 3).

```
In [12]: dateparse = lambda a,b,c: datetime.datetime.strptime(' '.join([a,b,c]), '%Y %j %H%M')

In [13]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), 
     header=None, 
     parse_dates=[[2,3,4]], 
     sep='\s+',skiprows=1, 
     date_parser=dateparse)
Out[13]: 
                2_3_4  0   1      5      6      7      8      9    10    11  12
0 2012-04-15 12:00:00  0  42 -0.325  0.576 -0.295  31.73  14.80  1096  99.3  55
1 2012-04-15 12:00:00  1  42 -0.372  0.499 -0.236  31.74  14.80  1097  99.3  56
2 2012-04-15 12:00:00  2  42 -0.372  0.456 -0.212  31.74  14.80  1096  99.3  57
3 2012-04-15 12:00:00  3  42 -0.312  0.736 -0.095  31.70  14.81  1097  99.3  58
4 2012-04-15 12:00:00  4  42 -0.352  0.707 -0.035  31.66  14.78  1094  99.3  59
5 2012-04-15 12:00:00  5  42 -0.518  0.662 -0.152  31.66  14.79  1094  99.3  60
6 2012-04-15 12:00:00  6  42 -0.516  0.531 -0.249  31.78  14.79  1094  99.3  61
```

Here are some more methods

```
In [45]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')

In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
    0     1    2     3      4      5      6      7      8     9    10  11
0  42  2012  106  1200 -0.325  0.576 -0.295  31.73  14.80  1096  99.3  55
1  42  2012  106  1200 -0.372  0.499 -0.236  31.74  14.80  1097  99.3  56
2  42  2012  106  1200 -0.372  0.456 -0.212  31.74  14.80  1096  99.3  57
3  42  2012  106  1200 -0.312  0.736 -0.095  31.70  14.81  1097  99.3  58
4  42  2012  106  1200 -0.352  0.707 -0.035  31.66  14.78  1094  99.3  59
5  42  2012  106  1200 -0.518  0.662 -0.152  31.66  14.79  1094  99.3  60
6  42  2012  106  1200 -0.516  0.531 -0.249  31.78  14.79  1094  99.3  61
```

Coerce back to strings, join and parse.

```
In [47]: pd.to_datetime(df['1'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['2'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['3'].astype(str), format='%Y %j %H%M')
Out[47]: 
0   2012-04-15 12:00:00
1   2012-04-15 12:00:00
2   2012-04-15 12:00:00
3   2012-04-15 12:00:00
4   2012-04-15 12:00:00
5   2012-04-15 12:00:00
6   2012-04-15 12:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Another method.

```
In [48]: pd.to_datetime(df['1'],format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(df['2'],unit='d') + pd.to_timedelta(df['3']/100,unit='h') + pd.to_timedelta(df['3']%100,unit='m') - Timedelta('1d')
Out[48]: 
0   2012-04-15 12:00:00
1   2012-04-15 12:00:00
2   2012-04-15 12:00:00
3   2012-04-15 12:00:00
4   2012-04-15 12:00:00
5   2012-04-15 12:00:00
6   2012-04-15 12:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```