# Convert date/time columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data sets containing the date (Julian day, column 1), hour (HHMM, column 2) and seconds (column 3) in individual columns:

```
1  253  2300   0    2.9  114.4  18.42  21.17
1  253  2300  10   3.27  111.2  18.48  21.12
1  253  2300  20   3.22  111.3  18.49  21.09
1  253  2300  30   3.84  106.4  18.52     21
1  253  2300  40   3.75  104.4  18.53  20.85
```

I'm reading the text file using `Pandas` as:

```
columns = ['station','julian_day','hours','seconds','U','Ud','T','RH']
df = pd.read_table(file_name, header=None, names=columns, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Now I want to convert the date to something more convenient like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (*The year isn't provided in the data set, but is fixed at 2001*).

I tried combining the three columns into one using `parse_dates`:

```
df = pd.read_table(file_name, header=None, names=columns, delim_whitespace=True, 
                   parse_dates={'datetime' : ['julian_day','hours','seconds']})
```

which converts the three columns into one string:

```
In [38]: df['datetime'][0]
Out[38]: '253 2300 0'
```

I next tried to convert them using `date_parser`; following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20500819/3581217) using something like:

```
date_parser = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%j %H%M %s')
```

The `date_parser` itself works, but I can't get this to combine with `read_table`, and I'm pretty much stuck at this point. Is there an easy way to achieve the conversion?

The full minimal (not-so) working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from io import StringIO

data_file = StringIO("""\
 1  253  2300   0    2.9  114.4  18.42  21.17
 1  253  2300  10   3.27  111.2  18.48  21.12
 1  253  2300  20   3.22  111.3  18.49  21.09
 1  253  2300  30   3.84  106.4  18.52     21
 1  253  2300  40   3.75  104.4  18.53  20.85
""")

date_parser = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%j %H%M %S')

columns = ['station','julian_day','hours','seconds','U','Ud','T','RH']
df = pd.read_table(data_file, header=None, names=columns, delim_whitespace=True,\
                   parse_dates={'datetime' : ['julian_day','hours','seconds']})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I am missing something but this seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from io import StringIO

data_file = StringIO("""\
 1  253  2300   0    2.9  114.4  18.42  21.17
 1  253  2300  10   3.27  111.2  18.48  21.12
 1  253  2300  20   3.22  111.3  18.49  21.09
 1  253  2300  30   3.84  106.4  18.52     21
 1  253  2300  40   3.75  104.4  18.53  20.85
""")

date_parser = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(("2001 " + x), '%Y %j %H%M %S')

columns = ['station','julian_day','hours','seconds','U','Ud','T','RH']
df = pd.read_table(data_file, header=None, names=columns, delim_whitespace=True,\
                   date_parser = date_parser,parse_dates={'datetime' : ['julian_day','hours','seconds']})
```

I just add the **date_parser** parameter in read_table and hard codded **2001** in parsing function.

Comment: Now I'm also not sure what I am (or was...) missing, but this indeed works. I'm sure I tried this approach, but there must have been a typo or something. Anyhow thanks, it's working now!

Comment: It is/was my (imperfect) real-life data set which is/was screwing me over.

Answer (score 1):

Would something along these lines work? :

```
def merge_date(df, year='Year', month='Month', day='Day', hours='Hours', seconds='Seconds'):
    """
    * Function: merge_date 
    * Usage: merge_date(DataFrame, col_year, col_month, col_day) . . .
    * -------------------------------
    * This function returns Datetime in the format YYYY-MM-DD from
    * input of a dataframe with columns holding 'Year', 'Month', 'Day' 
    """

    df['DateTime'] = df[[year, month, day, hours, seconds]].apply(lambda s : datetime.datetime(*s),axis = 1)
    return df
```

use `datetime.datetime` with argument unpacking for each dataframe column

Comment: Something like this: `df['datetime'].apply(date_parser)` indeed works as a post-processing step, but it would be nicer to do this at once while parsing the file